# Stata 13.0 import .csv file with traditional Chinese characters

Tags: csv, encoding, import, stata

Anyone knows how to import a csv file within which there is a column of traditional Chinese characters?

There is no choice like "text encoding" when I try to import delimited file using Stata.

Is it because Stata 13.0 is too outdated to fulfill this function? Because I saw someone choosing "text encoding" when importing using Stata 13.1.
If so, is there any chance I can update Stata 13.0 to Stata 13.1? I updated 13.0 to 2015/6/3, but it seems that it is still 13.0 but not 13.1.

Answer (score 2):

Stata 13.1 was released in October 2013 and is available to licensed users of 13.0 as an `update`. It is unclear why you can't do this.

It's my impression that updating to 13.1 will not add any functionality in support of Chinese characters as compared with 13.0.

However, Stata 14, released in 2015, added support for Unicode. See http://www.stata.com/stata14/unicode/

Use of Stata 14 will require an upgrade (not an `update`), i.e. purchase of a licence.